# Add column of WordNet synonyms to DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, nltk, wordnet

I have the below example DataFrame in the var output_table:

```
Job Title  ReqID  Word  TFAbs
Agree to Agree Manager  R4  Trust   2
Agree to Agree Manager  R4  agree   2
Agreement Manager   R2  Trust   5
```

I want to check synonyms of each word in column "Word" using WordNet. For that, I have the below code which works perfectly:

```
for ind in output_table.index: 
 word = output_table['List*(Term as String)'][ind]
 syn = list()
 for synset in wn.synsets(word):
    for lemma in synset.lemmas():
        syn.append(lemma.name())    
 df = DataFrame(syn,columns=['synonyms ' + word])
 print("Synonyms for gender word " + word + str(syn))
```

For the first row, the result is:

```
Synonyms for gender word Trust['trust', 'reliance', 'trust', 'trust', 'trustingness', 'trustfulness', 'trust', 'corporate_trust', 'combine', 'cartel', 'faith', 'trust', 'confidence', 'trust', 'trust', 'swear', 'rely', 'bank', 'trust', 'believe', 'trust', 'hope', 'trust', 'desire', 'entrust', 'intrust', 'trust', 'confide', 'commit', 'trust']
```

Now, I would like to add for each row a column containing all synonyms, for row 1 it would look like below:

```
Job Title  ReqID  Word  TFAbs  Synonyms
Agree to Agree Manager  R4  Trust   2  'trust', 'reliance', 'trust', 'trust', 'trustingness', 'trustfulness', 'trust', 'corporate_trust', 'combine', 'cartel', 'faith', 'trust', 'confidence', 'trust', 'trust', 'swear', 'rely', 'bank', 'trust', 'believe', 'trust', 'hope', 'trust', 'desire', 'entrust', 'intrust', 'trust', 'confide', 'commit', 'trust'
```

Tried multiple things (i.e. append), but I just don't get it to work... May I kindly ask for support?

Ty, mikvuk

Comment: Your _example DataFrame_ in contrast to your _code which works perfectly_ doesn't contain a column named `List*(Term as String)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .assign() to add the new values as a column. In order to do so, I first created a new column.

```
column = []
for ind in output_table.index: 
    word = output_table['Word'][ind]
    syn = list()
   
    for synset in wn.synsets(word):
        for lemma in synset.lemmas():
            syn.append(lemma.name())
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(syn,columns=['synonyms ' + word])
    print("Synonyms for gender word " + word + str(syn))
    column.append(syn)
output_table.assign(newcol = column)
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Minfetli

Worked perfectly after adding "output_table = " to the last line:

```
output_table = output_table.assign(newcol = column)
```

Cheers